# How do the momentum and spin of negative energy electrons (particles in the Dirac sea) and positrons (holes in the Dirac sea) differ?

Tags: momentum, electrons, quantum-spin

How do the momentum and spin of negative energy electrons (particles in the Dirac sea) and positrons (holes in the Dirac sea) differ? I just know that negative energy electrons and positrons have different charges. I would like to know more about their momentum and spin. Do they have the same momentum with opposite signs?

Answer (score 1):

Electrons and positrons can each have any momentum or spin. It is when you demand that the total momentum and spin of a system of electrons and positrons is, for example, zero that there is a relation.

Forget the Dirac sea. As an explanation of positrons it is a flawed concept. As an explanation of positively charged holes in matter, it is a brilliant idea.

Comment: What is the difference between positively charged holes and positrons?

Comment: Holes describe what happens if an electron is missing from a many electron system. Positrons are positively charged point particles.

Comment: And what is the difference between positively charged holes in the Dirac sea and positrons? Thanks for your patience

Comment: @TomášKubalík Positron is a fundamental/elementary particle. Holes are a description for lack of electrons in many-electron systems. They are not fundamental particles or even a particle.

Comment: @TomasKubalik The difference is that there is no Dirac sea. Even if there were, holes in it would not behave as positrons, just like holes in (semi)conductors for example have quite different effective mass from electrons. And why would an electron not also be a hole, in a sea of occupied positron orbitals?

Comment: Yes, that´s how I see it. An electron with negative energy is a hole in a sea of occupied positron orbitals.

Comment: Penrose in his Road to Reality says: But it was not
long before it became clear that the mass of each hole had to be
equal to the mass of the electron, rather than the mass of a proton,
which is about 1836 times larger." That´ s why I thought their mass is the same.

Comment: @TimasKubalik Of course, you meant negative frequency. However if every positron is a hole in a filled electron Dirac sea and each of these electrons is a hole in a filled Dirac positron sea, and so on, the number of filled Dirac seas is exploding. Also a hole in a real electron 'sea' behaves quite differently from a positron.